# How to convert distance in meters(EPSG:28406) to EPSG:900913 with OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, distance, epsg

For point I use OpenLayers and transform():

```
 numZona = Math.ceil(parseFloat(lon)/6));
 Proj4js.defs["EPSG:28406"] = '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0='(parseInt(numZona)*6-3)+' +k=1.000000 +x_0='+numZona+'500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=krass +units=m +no_defs;
 centerPoint = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon, lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4284"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));
```

But what do with distance? 
I have longitude and latitude in EPSG:4284, distanse in meters and a map with EPSG:900913 projection.

Comment: What you want to do? Why you want to get a distance in 900913?

Comment: Side note: if the false easting is 500000, that's EPSG:2496 instead (EPSG:28406 has a false easting of 6500000).

Comment: @JorgeSanz Calculating a new position in a map using OpenLayers:900913?

Comment: So you want from a position, azimuth and real world distance to locate a new point, all in represented in 900913?

Comment: @JorgeSanz Yes!

Answer (score 1):

So you what you want to do is the direct problem, I'd do all your calculations in your projected system or even better, transform it to geodetic coordinates and resolve what is called the [direct, or forward, problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid#Solution_of_the_direct_problem) and then simply get your new point in 900913.

It all depends then on source projected coordinates and the accuracy you are looking for. For example in UTM you have to take in account the anamorphosis coefficient for medium to large distances. That's why maybe solving the direct problem on the spheroid (4326) is more accurate. You can look for some JavaScript code for the inverse and direct problems [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html).